# android dialog orientation issue

Tags: android, screen-orientation

hi i am new developer on android i have written code for display simple dialog,in this dialog i have taken edit text view.when i entered text on edit text then i have changed orientation of the scree then the value of edit text has not appearing!

i have written code as follows

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  

alert.setTitle("Title");  
alert.setMessage("Message");  

// Set an EditText view to get user input   
final EditText input = new EditText(this);  
alert.setView(input);  

alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {  
  String value = input.getText();  
  // Do something with value!  
  }  
});  

alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {  
    // Canceled.  
  }  
});  

alert.show();
```

please any one can resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, this involves overriding the onRetainNonConfigurationInstance method.
See here: 
[Faster Screen Orientation Change](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html)

Excerpt:

> "The Activity class has a special
>   method called
>   onRetainNonConfigurationInstance().
>   This method can be used to pass an
>   arbitrary object your future self and
>   Android is smart enough to call this
>   method only when needed. In the case
>   of Photostream, the application used
>   this method to pass the downloaded
>   images to the future activity on
>   orientation change."

Answer (score 1):

prasad... The editText box does not have an ID and if the view element does not have an ID the view state is not automagically saved on a soft kill when the user changes the orientation of the phone. You might be better off creating a custom dialog using an XML layout, then the edit text box should have and ID and the view state should be automagically saved on a soft kill.

JAL

I have some code [here](http://sites.google.com/site/jalcomputing/home/mac-osx-android-programming-tutorial/custom-password-dialog).

Edit: Prototype code taken from the Android Docs that barely works because I do not have the time to work on this. Create an XML layout in res/layout as alert_dialog_text_entry.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<EditText android:text="Stateful" 
android:id="@+id/EditText01" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

And then use this layout to create the alert:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
    LayoutInflater inflater= getLayoutInflater();
    final View myView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_text_entry, null);
    builder.setTitle("About");
    builder.setMessage(alertMessage+"Version: "+versionName);
    builder.setView(myView);
    AlertDialog alert= builder.create();
```

Since the editText box has an ID it appears to save state on a soft kill.

Comment: @prasad gai OK I will add prototype "it barely works" code to get you started

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but it is still worth giving a simpler answer. JAL mentions the need to set the ID, but you can go ahead and do that directly in the Java. For example, add this new line into the original code above:

```
// Set an EditText view to get user input   
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
// Id the EditText so the framework will save/restore it for us
input.setId(R.id.my_id_for_alert_box_inputs); // <-------- New line
alert.setView(input);
```

Under `/res/values` create a new XML file called `ids.xml`. In there, define this id we use in the Java:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Integer IDs used for tagging Views made in Java programmatically
     without clashing with XML-defined views.   -->
<resources>
  <!-- Used to id the input box in a dialog. Reused in different dialogs. -->
  <item type="id" name="my_id_for_alert_box_inputs" />
</resources>
```

This works because the Android application framework is supposed to save/restore views that have an ID defined. The whole XML part of the above is neat but not really needed. You could just plug a made-up integer into the Java `View.setId()` call to make this a one-line fix.